# Как запретить использовать приложение без интернета?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, безопасность

У меня всё время выполняются запросы, и, если отключить интернет и зайти в приложение, то всегда краш, а проверки ставить всюду затратно.

Есть ли универсальное решение?

Comment: Я попробовал немного улучшить формулировку для большей понятности. Если моё изменение не отражает вашей цели, откатите его, используя историю правок.

Comment: А если интернет отключится во время работы приложения, что должно произойти?

Comment: Хотите, чтобы приложение не запускалось без рекламных баннеров, ага? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно по разному:

1. Проверять на входе в приложение наличие интернета, т.е. при запуске главного `Activity`. И не стартовать к-л задачи до успешной проверки.
2. Сделать активити-проверщик интернета. Запускать на нынешнюю главную а эту. Если интернет есть, то запускать нынешнюю главную. Иначе - выходить из приложения.
3. Обернуть все нынешние запросы в сеть в класс, проверяющий перед запуском задачи наличие инета. Если он есть - продолжаем, иначе - закрываем приложение.

Проверить же наличие соединения с сетью (не факт, что там есть сам интернет) можно, согласно en-SO, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009133/3212712):

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Также надо добавить спец. разрешение в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Ещё момент: если надо проверять именно факт подключённости с интернету (а не `подключено-или-подключается`) то использовать надо `netInfo.isConnected()` вместо  `netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()`.

---

Проверить же есть ли интернет как таковой можно вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/3212712):

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //можно заменить на к-л другой сайт

        if (ipAddr.equals("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

И не забываем про все нужные разрешения в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Увы, но Ваш метод проверяет лишь наличие подключения к сети оператора или провайдера, но не наличие выхода в Интернет.

Comment: @web_alex, да, действительно. Добавил код из второй строки выдачи гугла на запрос `check internet connection android` =)

Comment: Этот метод тоже не поможет.

Comment: @web_alex, а этот чем плох?..

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из описания вам однозначно нужно делать редизайн приложения и реализовывать запросы через отдельный класс который будет в том числе и обслуживать все ошибки сети.
Для носимых устройств обычным делом является интернет, который может пропасть в любой момент и в любой момент появится опять, что нивелирует проверку соединения при старте приложения, т.к. оно может пропасть сразу же после проверки или же наоборот появится сразу после выхода из приложения.